# Regex allow max 3 numbers and one dot

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i try to catch an input of a field via javascript.

i need to get max 3 numbers and one dot.

i tried this regex: `[^\d{0,3}.{0,1}\d{0,3}]`

but it isn't quite working, i can't really get how to fetch the numeric values globaly so it is really max 3 numbers.

```
333   //ok
333   //ok
33.1  //ok
3.33  //ok
3.3.  //not ok
3.333 //not ok
3333. //not ok
3..   //not ok
.     //not ok
```

Hope someone can give me a hint here.

Comment: Can it start with a dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **on-submit (final) validation**, you can use

```js
^(?=.{3,4}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ru1O3/1/). It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,4}$)` - this requires the string to have three or four chars only
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits, and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits. As `\d`, `\.` and `\d` are obligatory to match at least once, the min limit as 3 is justified and since only one dot can be matched, either of `\d+` can match one or two digits, but only three all in all
- `$` - end of string.

For **live input text validation**, you can use

```js
^(?:\d{1,3}|\d(?:\d?\.\d?|\.\d{2}))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ru1O3/3/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a group:

  - `\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `|` - or

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `(?:\d?\.\d?|\.\d{2})` - a non-capturing group matching either

    - `\d?\.\d?` - an optional digit, a `.` and then an optional digit
    - `|` - or
    - `\.\d{2}` - `.` and then two digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to "negate" the selection so the 3.3. etc. are selected. Is there an easy way to do that? Thank you!

Comment: @lvollmer Negating is done like `^(?!pattern$)`. So, `^(?!(?=.{3,4}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$)`

Comment: Like this https://regex101.com/r/1YzFjM/1 ? i thought it would select the others then.

Comment: @lvollmer Yes, it did. If you want to consume the lines, add `.*` at the end.

Comment: how can i select only the +x characters of a string? so like 33381 the 81?

Comment: @lvollmer Maybe `^(?=.{3,4}$)\d*?(\d{1,2})(?:\.\d+)?$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ru1O3/4).

Comment: Unfortunately not, i put it in a https://jsfiddle.net/jfuve3p1/ here. The content gets deleted when a certain character or more is typed, but it should just avoid putting it in.

Comment: @lvollmer Sorry, this does not look like the same issue, the number you provided has more than 3 digits in the integer part and cannot be input. I don't understand the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I am very bad in regex but came up with something like this below. Probably there is a much more elegant way but....

```
^\d{0,3}$|^\d{2}[.]\d{1}$|^\d{1}[.]\d{1,2}$
```

Works for MAX 3 numbers so 3 and 33 is also ok

Answer (score 1):

You might also match all 3 variations in a non capture group:

```
^(?:\d{3}|\d\.\d\d|\d\d\.\d)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pYP3em/1)

Or first match a single digit followed by 2 variations of an optional dot and 2 digits or a single digit, optional dot and a single digit:

```
^\d(?:\.?\d\d|\d\.?\d)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE9TIM/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
(?<!\.)\b\d\.?\d\.?\d\b
```

I have tested with all your cases and it works fine.